# Error 'was unexpected at this time' al ejecutar bat

Tags: batch

Estoy ejecutando un fichero .bat que contiene lo siguiente:

```
FOR %A IN (1 2 3 4 5) DO (
echo %A
)
```

Me aparece el siguiente error:

```
A was unexpected at this time.
```

Si lo ejecuto manualmente, es decir, copiando el texto me devuelve los numeros correctamente.
Porque en un fichero me provoca este error? Como se puede solucionar?

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba así:

```
for %%a in (1,2,3,4,5) do (
    echo %%a
)
```

Curiosamente, desde el intérprete de comandos me falla con el mismo error que a ti, pero desde un fichero .bat me funciona correctamente.

Comment: genial! con uno '%' de mas funciona